# AMP Stories along AMP Wordpress Plugin, is it available now?

Tags: wordpress

I was trying out AMP and wanted to make it work with Wordpress. I found the https://amp-wp.org plugin. I primarily want to explore **AMP Stories**, so when I read the plugin documentation here - https://amp-wp.org/documentation/amp-stories/ it says that AMP Stories are coming out as a separate plugin. So I checked https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/amp+stories/ but I couldn't find a plugin by the - **AMP Project Contributors** . So is this plugin still in pipeline?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As an engineer working on both the official AMP plugin and on Stories, I am happy to answer your question.

First of all, it's great that you're interested in Stories! I'd be curious to learn more about the specific project you're envisioning to use Stories on. Would you mind sharing some more details about this?

To answer your question: **Yes**, this plugin is actively being worked on and it's **coming soon**! We want to make sure we create a captivating solution for visual storytelling that WordPress users will love, that's why you can't find it yet on WordPress.org. It'll take at least another month until we feel comfortable sharing the new Stories plugin with the community.

Once it's ready, we will make sure to announce it on various channels and update the https://amp-wp.org/ website accordingly. Until then, you might want to follow development progress [on GitHub](https://github.com/google/web-stories-wp).

**Update July 2023**:

The official [Web Stories for WordPress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/web-stories/) was launched back in summer 2020 and is now used on over 100k websites!

Comment: Thank you so much for the update. I would love to share more details about the product I am working on and see a great use of this plugin. Would will do that shortly. Thanks